# Chef execute block

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am very new to `Chef`. I have a recipe that installs `sendmail` and it does my configurations. I have noticed that `Chef` restarts the service on every run. That is because I'm running an `execute` that calls the session restart.

It looks like this:

```
execute "hashAccess" do
  command "makemap hash /etc/mail/access < /etc/mail/access"
  notifies :restart, "service[sendmail]"
end
```

I need to call this only when the `access` file if updated.

```
template "/etc/mail/access" do
  source "access.erb"
  mode   "0644"
  notifies :run, "execute[hashAccess]"
end
```

When the file is updated, the `execute` is called twice.
Both of the resources are in the same recipe and when I try to `define` `hashAccess` I get an error

```
 ERROR: Cannot find a resource for define on amazon version 2013.09
```

How do I make the execute resource to run only when called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add `action :nothing` to your execute resource.

```
execute "hashAccess" do
  command "makemap hash /etc/mail/access < /etc/mail/access"
  action :nothing
  notifies :restart, "service[sendmail]"
end
```

This way it will not be executed, unless notified by other resource.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would be simple... :)